# d3 - Can you sort by categorical variables?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have overlapping data points on my dot plot and read that d3 does not support the z-index as a way to order larger elements (e.g. circles) below smaller ones.  I read that one of the workarounds that d3 offers is the `sort` function.  In order to get the larger circles under the smaller ones, my data, however, needs to be sorted by categorical variables.  My dataset looks like the following:

```
year,rs,team,ra,champs,finals
2002,897,bears,697,yes,no
2003,877,bears,716,no,yes
2004,897,bears,808,no,yes
2002,873,lions,653,no,no
2003,765,lions,823,yes,no
2004,834,lions,722,no,yes
…
```

I am interested in ordering my data so that records with `champs==="yes"` are plotted first, then those with `finals==="yes"`, then finally all the others.  How could I use the `data.sort()` function to support such an ordering?  Or, is there a better way?

Comment: There's nothing in d3 preventing you setting z-index on an element, via the `style()` method. It's the SVG spec that doesn't support the z-index property. Assume you're using SVG then, which z-orders elements based on their order in the DOM, you'll be able to control this order via `selection.sort()` ([api reference link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-sort)). It's impossible to provide any more applicable answer without seeing the code that creates those elements.

Comment: You can create another column and populate it using an if statement and then sort it.  So something if champs === "yes" sort = 1 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As meetamit pointed out, the lack of `z-index` support isn't due to D3, but due to SVG. This means that if you're not using SVG to render your visualisation, it should be fine.

To do the sorting, you don't even have to use D3's sort, but you can use the vanilla Javascript [sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). It takes a sort function that allows you to control how elements are sorted. If it returns a number < 0, the first element is less than the second, if > 0, it's greater. So you would have something like

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
  if(a.champs === "yes" && b.champs === "no") {
    return -1;
  } else if(a.champs === "no" && b.champs === "yes") {
    return 1;
  } else if(a.finals === "yes" && b.finals === "no") {
    return -1;
  } else if(a.finals === "no" && b.finals === "yes") {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```